Is thick or thin wire better for motor winding?
When winding a motor, is it better to use thick copper wire or thin copper wire? Keep in mind the space is limited so using a thin wire will lead to more turns and thick wire would give less turns in the same space.
QUESTION:

Which wire would be better for more power?
Is it like thick wire gives more torque and less RPM and for thin wire it is high RPM low torque?


Like any electrical wire size, the size is determined by the motor's full load current (FLA).

Having chosen the power of the motor, and its volume and weight, and the space available for winding, and so the weight of the copper, you have finished that part of the design. To first order, the thickness of the copper wire, and the number of turns, are irrelevant. Only the mass of copper matters for power and efficiency, speed and torque.
Now, if you want to deliver the electrical power at a high voltage and low current, you use thin wire. If you want a low voltage high current motor, you use thick wire.
This is true over quite a range of 'reasonable' wire sizes, but there are limits to how extreme you can choose the thickness of the wire.
Very thick wire is difficult to wind, and the difference between N and N+1 turns in the available winding space may be significant. High current means you will need thick lead-in wires, and high current design throughout your power supply.
Very thin wire is difficult to handle without breaking, and takes a long time to wind. The insulation cannot be made arbitrarily thin, so as the wire becomes thinner, the effective copper area fraction reduces. A very high voltage might be a safety problem for your application, and force the wire insulation to be yet thicker than needed just for mechanical integrity.
Generally the application will define the voltage, or at least the range of voltages, for you, from toy motors running from AA batteries, to 800 V motors for EVs, and everything in between and beyond.
